# How can I make backspace act as escape using setxkbmap?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xkb

There seem to be several options for `setxkbmap` such as `-option caps:backspace` which makes caps a backspace. However I cannot seem to find an option that makes backspace an escape key. How do I create a single setxkbmap command that changes the backspace key to an escape key?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll have to define a new option.
First, make a new symbol file e.g. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/bksp` with the following content:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "bksp_escape" {
    key <BKSP> { [ Escape ] };
};
```

---

Then create the new option like this:

```
bksp:bksp_escape  =   +bksp(bksp_escape)
```

(where `bksp` is the name of the symbol file and `bksp_escape` is the group name that was defined in this file) and add it to the options list in the rules set you're using - assuming `evdev` - so place it in  `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev` under `! option  =   symbols`:

```
! option    =   symbols
  bksp:bksp_escape  =   +bksp(bksp_escape)
  ...........
  grp:shift_toggle  =   +group(shifts_toggle)
  altwin:menu       =   +altwin(menu)
```

Add it also to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst` (with a short description) under `! option` (e.g. right before `ctrl`):

```
! option
  ........
  bksp                 Backspace key behavior
  bksp:bksp_escape     Backspace as Escape
  ctrl                 Ctrl key position
  ctrl:nocaps          Caps Lock as Ctrl
```

---

You can then run, as a regular user:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option bksp:bksp_escape
```

to enable the option and make <kbd>BKSP</kbd> behave as <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
You can also verify if:

```
setxkbmap -query
```

reports:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     us
options:    bksp:bksp_escape
```

and if

```
setxkbmap -print
```

outputs:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+bksp(bksp_escape)" };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

---

In Gnome 3 you can make the option permanent via `dconf` (or `gsettings` in terminal) e.g. add `'bksp:bksp_escape'` to the *org​>gnome​>desktop​>input-sources​>xkb-options* key (note that in `dconf` values are separated by comma+space).

---

Finally, note that both `evdev` and `evdev.lst` will be overwritten on future upgrades (but not your custom `bksp` symbol file) so you'll have to edit them again each time the package that owns them is upgraded (on archlinux it's `xkeyboard-config`). It's easier to write a script that does that, e.g.

```
sed '/! option[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*symbols/a\
  bksp:bksp_escape  =   +bksp(bksp_escape)
' /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev

sed '/! option/a\
  bksp                 Backspace key behavior\
  bksp:bksp_escape     Backspace as Escape
' /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst
```

If you're happy with the result use `sed -i` (or `-i.bak` if you want to make backup copies) to actually edit those files *in-place*.