# Swap shift and caps-lock

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xkb

I would like to swap the behavior of the two keys <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on my keyboard.

I have read the options in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`, played around with'em, but none of them seems to be the exact one I need.

Is this possible? If yes, how should I do?

Comment: It is possible if you define a custom option, like [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215062). It's pretty much the same procedure only the first step (the symbols file) is different (you'll have to use `replace key`). You think you can handle that or do you want me to rewrite it here, tailored to your needs ?

Comment: @don_crissti This looks promising! I'll have a try.

Answer (score 1):

The tools to manipulate the keyboard layout on the virtual consoles are loadkeys, dumpkeys and showkeys. Read their manpages and inform yourself about their intricacies.

Note that these tools only work in a virtual console, not in a terminal emulator in a graphical environment like gnome. The learn about the difference read this question and answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal.

Look at this example:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html

Comment: Why not. I'll have a try if creating a new option as suggested by don_crissti doesn't work. Unfortunately, I would like it to work in the graphical environment as well.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian with Gnome you can install `gnome-tweak-tool`. In the secton "Typing" there are loads of available behaviors for Caps Lock

Comment: I guess there are pretty much the same as the ones in `base.lst`, and unfortunately none of them is the one I need :\