# xkb: how toggle keyboard layout with win + capslock?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to set custom shortcut to change keyboard layout using `setxkbmap`. For example `win_caps` (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd>). This option is not listed in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to define your own custom option ([example](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215062)).

Comment: @don_crissti I haven't got a time to try to write it with all the grasp I could gather, but after a hour or so browsing through the Internet I still didn't get how to write custom grp toggle option. If you could at least give me a link to some kind of comprehensive xkb configuration guide I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to define a custom option e.g. `win_caps_toggle`.
Add the following definition to your `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/group`:

```
// toggle using win + capslock as combo
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "win_caps_toggle" {
    key <CAPS> {
        type[Group1]="PC_SUPER_LEVEL2",
        symbols[Group1] = [ Caps_Lock, ISO_Next_Group ]
    };
};
```

and the following description to your `usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`:

```
grp:win_caps_toggle Win+Caps Lock
```

anywhere under the `grp` section (e.g. under `grp:caps_toggle`).
You can then run

```
setxkbmap -option grp:win_caps_toggle
```

to set <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as the shortcut that changes the keyboard layout.

---

**Note**: this solution doesn't work with gnome 3. I think in order to make it work some stuff has to be disabled in gnome; I've tried disabling `gnome-settings-daemon` keyboard plugin and `mutter` overview key but no go. Works fine with other DE's though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to implement this tomorrow, as I'll have time for it. And please, can you give me a link to some kind of docs that would explain the process of xkb configuration?

Comment: I think this doesn't work in gnome because [gnome-shell implements differently the work with XKB](https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/1877#issuecomment-254395171). Sorry for not being more specific, I don't speak XKB.