# How to set layout toggle on <win+caps> in configuration.nix?

Tags: configuration, nixos

How can I set layout toggling on `<win+caps>` in NixOS `configuration.nix` **only**?

Comment: Are you referring to Xorg keyboard options? For example, I use `configuration.nix` to set up ALT+SHIFT to toggle the keyboard language between English and Thai.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa It could be easily done with just setting `services.xserver.xkbOptions` to `"grp:win_caps_toggle"`, but first custom `win_caps_toggle` option should be defined; here is the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244883/xkb-how-toggle-keyboard-layout-with-win-capslock/246491#246491) how to do it, but can it be done in `configuration.nix` only? BTW saw your vids about NixOS installation.

Comment: Oh, thanks for watching! Here's the scoop. There's no built-in way in NixOS options to modify the files described in the answer you linked to. It can be done, but there's one piece I don't know how to do. Basically, you need to create a derivation which contains "${pkgs.xkeyboard_config}/etc/X11/xkb}" plus the files you need to override; namely `share/X11/xkb/symbols/group` and `share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`. To do this you need the nixpkgs function which recursively symlinks a tree of files. For the life of me, I cannot remember the name of this function....

Comment: ...With that in place then set `services.xserver.xkbDir` to the output of said derivation. When Xorg runs it will use the `xkbDir` for keyboard settings. Since it would point to the same files it currently does (due to the symlink-ing) PLUS the custom files you provide, that should allow you to use <win+caps> in NixOS with `configuration.nix`. The final step is setting `services.xserver.xkbOptions = "grp:win_caps_toggle";` Overall, this will require some troubleshooting, hence I recommend asking in the NixOS Discourse community or on IRC.