# Using xkb to remap quote and Right Control

Tags: xkb

On a standard US keyboard, I've swapped <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Left Control</kbd>, which is almost essential for proper `Emacs` usage.

For symmetry, I'd like to swap <kbd>'</kbd> (the `quote` key) to <kbd>Right Control</kbd>. `xkb` seems like the tool to do this, but there's a whole lot of complexity with rules files, groups, etc. that I can't get my head around.

Can I see an example of how this would be done? I'm guessing that there's some  special complexity about trying to turn a non-modifier key into a modifier key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` and swap keycodes, e.g. on my system the keycode for quote key is `48` and respectively `105` for the right ctrl so just comment the original lines (prepend `//`) and swap values:

```
//    <AC11> = 48;
    <AC11> = 105;
    ...........
//    <RCTL> = 105;
    <RCTL> = 48;
```

A better way would be to add a new option to your `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ctrl` e.g.

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "swapquotes" {
    replace key <AC11> { [ Control_R ] };
    replace key <RCTL> { [ apostrophe,  quotedbl ] };
};
```

that you could then load/unload via `setxkbmap`. If you use this method you may want to list the new option along with a short description in your `evdev.lst` (see [the post here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215062) for more details).