# Suddenly xkbcomp stopped working

Tags: x11, gnome, keyboard-layout, xkb, wayland

I have a working keyboard setup in my `.xkbmap` and make it active by `xkbcomp $HOME/.xkbmap $DISPLAY`. But it suddenly stopped working. Somehow it does not change keyboard settings. I am totally confused.

I am using Debian/testing with Gnome.

Comment: xkbcomp is not working with gdm3 but it works with lightdm.

Comment: Isn't this the [same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389471/117549)?

Comment: nope! Now it is not working at all. In the previous question, it was working for a while.

Comment: so the previous question should be closed?

Comment: I think previous question is about suddenly xkbcomp stop working after some time.  But this question is now that it is not working at all. I know that xmodmap doesn't work with Xwayland. But it is strange that xkbcomp doesn't work either.

Comment: it just seems to me that if it's not working at all, then we don't have a hope of answering the previous question.

Comment: Sure we could close that one. Maybe there was a problem due to my recent upgrade to xwayland.

Comment: I am not sure but xkbcomp may not working in Wayland as in Xorg. (so xmodmap and xkbcomp are useless to change the keyboard in Wayland.)

Comment: If you're using wayland, you may want to use that tag instead of x11 -- people may search by tags and miss yours if it's not tagged correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really helpfully in questions if instead of "suddenly it stopped working" you actually describe the circumstances, as an "after my recent upgrade to xwayland".

While Wayland uses `xkb`, it works in a [different way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309580/does-wayland-use-xkb-for-keyboard-layouts) from X, and details depend on the compositor.

So if you are doing `xkbcomp $HOME/.xkbmap $DISPLAY`, `xkbmap` uses the X protocol to contact XWayland, which promptly ignores it because there's no way to change keyboard mappings in Wayland proper while running. So your upgrade to XWayland broke things (which is not really surprising, considering they are completely differet systems), and it didn't "suddenly stopped working".

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292868/how-to-customise-keyboard-mappings-with-wayland) explains how to customise your keyboard mappings with wayland.
Basically you need to change (or better: add to) the system XKB database.