# How can I assign "control" functionality to the right super (windows) key in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc?

Tags: keyboard, xkb, x-server

I am trying to assign "control" to my *Super R* key in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`.

So, I change

```
key <RWIN> { [ Super_R ] }
```

to

```
key <RWIN> { [ Control_R ] }
```

Then I start `X` and use `xev` to verify that the change took place. Indeed, `xev` reports `Control_R` when I press my right "super" (windows) key.

However, when I want to use `ctrl-c` or `ctrl-d` by pressing the right super key and c or d, respectively, a program is not stopped nor is a shell exited.
It works as always when I use the left control key.

If I exit X and *also* change

```
key <RCTL> { [ Control_R ] }
```

to

```
key <RCTL> { [ Super_R ] }
```

and then start `X` again, the right super key behaves as the control key. However, the right control key does not behave as control anymore, which is undesired by me.

So, I am wondering why the first change did not bring the desired keyboard changes about and how I can assign control functionality to the right super key.

Comment: If you are using X (and not Wayland), and simpler way may be to use `xmodmap`. XKB is a bit complicated, and if you meddle with existing files, all your changes will be gone the next time you update the corresponding package. The proper way using XKB is to add your own keyboard layout.

Comment: You have to define a new `xkb` option, [see my post here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212573/22142). There is already an option that does what you want but it's for both Super keys: `altwin:ctrl_win` so all you have to do is edit the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin` and add a new option like e.g. `ctrl_rwin` that maps control only to right super. Just copy the code from `ctrl_win` and remove the `LWIN` stuff, the rest is in my post over there (your case is easier as you just edit existing files, you don't need to create a new file).