# use setkbdmap to map right alt to backspace

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I want the the key to right of `space` which has `AltGr` written on it (the output of `xev` is however `Alt_R`) to perform the the same action as backspace. I tried almost every random combination of `setxkbmap backspace:ralt` i could come up.

PS: I am running i3 on Lubuntu.

Comment: It makes sense to run `localectl list-x11-keymap-options` to see the available options instead of trying _"almost every random combination"_. If you can't find an option that does what you want you'll have to [write a new `xkb` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/212573/22142).

Comment: the option I'm looking for does in fact not exist. writing ones own xkb option seems rather tedious and overly complicated for a - imho - standard task as button remapping, but whatever. more importantly, the /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev file mentioned in the answer you linked says in the first line "do not edit this". whom should I trust now? (and is there no easier way?)